# How do I restore my Windows 10 from grub?

Tags: grub2, windows-10

please help. I dual booted Ubuntu with my Win 10. After a few weeks, I decided to delete ubuntu and try some other Linux distro. Well I deleted Ubuntu from my Win 10. But now when I start up my PC, it shows Grub Error: Partition not found. I googled it and tried to find solutions to it. Well, the solution that I found really likely to work was to use my Win 10 bootable USB. But after I installed Win 10 from my usb, I deleted all the setup files from my USB. So I need to make a bootable USB again, but I only have one PC, and because of the grub error I can't get inside of my OS. Please help me to restore back my Win 10.

PS. I am just a student, I really loved Linux and want to continue using it.

Comment: Look into using [BootRepair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) or the Windows boot repair https://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows which might have to be done from a Windows bootable media.  GRUB is not loading because it uses libraries and applications that were in the Ubuntu software.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, just press the UEFI boot menu key, often f10 or f12, check your manual and choose Windows. If BIOS you probably can just use Boot-Repair and Ubuntu live installer to install a generic Windows type boot loader to MBR. You always need repair or recovery flash drives for all systems you have installed. And good backups.

Comment: I don't see how creating a new Windows 10 install USB is an Ubuntu support issue. If you had Ubuntu installed, perhaps...but you don't.